# Determining which set of edges causes a negative cycle?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, mathematical-optimization, shortest-path, directed-graph

I have a directed graph G = (V, E) where edges have weights. Some edges may have negative weights, but G does not contain any negative cycles.

I have a set of new edges S that, if added to G, will cause a negative cycle. I would like to determine which of these edges, when added to G, cause the negative cycle. How could I do this?

Comment: Bellman-Ford can identify negative cycles in O(VE). If you keep track if the predecessor for each vertex then you can identify the edges in that cycle. From there you see which of them were from the set of new edges.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remarks. you are right, but the problem is what if the new negative cycle contains more than one new edge, in this case which one to remove ( there are more than one possibility) so which one is better. I mean, I don't know if my decision in this case is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by using the delta-debugging algorithm. This was originally designed for identifying minimal test cases or minimal change sets that cause a program to crash, but it should work here as well.

In the delta-debugging algorithm, you begin with some configuration that works and have a set of changes C where applying C to the baseline configuration will cause a failure. If you assume C obeys a specific property, then you can, making only O(|C|<sup>2</sup>) tests, determine a minimal set of changes that will cause a failure. The property required is the following: If S is a set of changes that causes a failure and S ⊆ S', then S' will cause a failure as well.

In your case, the baseline set is the original graph and your set of changes are the set of edges you added into the graph. If you add in a set of edges that causes a negative cycle to appear, then adding in any set containing those edges will also cause the cycle to appear. Therefore, if you have a graph with m nodes, n edges, and you have z candidate edges, you can in O(z<sup>2</sup>) iterations of Bellman-Ford (runtime O((m + z)n)) determine a minimal set of edges that will cause a negative cycle to appear. The runtime will be O(z<sup>2</sup>(m + z)n), which for small z is not too bad.

Details about the algorithm can be found in [the original paper](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/publications/files/zeller-esec-1999.pdf) or [this set of lecture slides](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps290g/Winter04/lectures/flanagan-290g-8.pdf).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ford-Bellman algorithm is able to detect whether graph has cycle of negative weight. If your issue can be restated like

> Given graph `G = (V, E)` and a set of edges S, find out if adding **one** of the edges creates a negative-weight cycle in the graph.

For such formulation it is quite easy - you just add (and remove, if no cycle found) new edges one-by-one and check if graph now has negative cycle.

If your task is more generic, like

> Given ...[same], find out the minimal subset(s) of edges from S which cause graph to have negative cycle

Then you need to run Ford-Bellman for much more times. I mean, first - for all added subsets of one edge (like I wrote above), then for all subsets of two edges, and so on.